# Emacs eww - how to switch to typing in text fields?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs, evil-mode, eww

I'm new to eww browser(and emacs) and was wondering if it is possible to use it not just for navigating links and URLs but for submitting some basic plain HTML forms.

Is it possible?

I was trying to test in using https://google.com, it sort-of-works but certain characters activate various modes/commands in emacs. Like SPC, k, l etc so I can't enter those.

If it is relevant, I use Spacemacs + Evil mode + https://github.com/coljamkop/eww-layer

Comment: You mean when cursor is in the text field and you try typing text, emacs shortcuts are active? It's not how it works by default. To be sure just tested it on google.com - yep, I can type in the search field whatever I want. But I don't use evil-mode and eww-layer.

Comment: thanks @rsm! You just gave me a hint it might be related to evil-mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was related to how eww+evil-mode was configured in spacemacs.

Related issue https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/4107 as of Nov 2019 it is still work in progress.

As a workaround, I run `evil-insert` manually to activate the insert mode.